# Excel help: check two columns for matching row, copy in new data

Tags: excel-2010

I have two excel data sources I need to combine into a single list. I'm sure this question has been asked in a different way but I couldn't get any of the suggested formulas I found in my searching to work for me!

At the moment, each list sits on a separate tab and is organised as below

Table 1

```
| Account | Amount | reference| NEW REFERENCE |
```

Table 2

```
| NEW REFERENCE | Reference | Amount |
```

What I want to do is, where Reference and amount values match on a line, pull the NEW Reference into the first table from the 2nd.

The items are in a different order.

There are instances where there are duplicates in the 'reference' column, but these are differentiated the by the values in the Amount column and vice versa.

Where two rows match based on  both of these columns, Ideally I'd like to highlight these but could live without it.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2016 so I am not positive on what the tabs/functions are called exactly for 2010:

You should have either a data or reference tab. Select all of the columns of data. On one of your excel sheets/workbooks, click the "From Table/Range" button (should be within the get & transform data section).

[image]

Once the query editor opens, you will need to add a new source (the second excel worksheet you want to join to this one); select file > Excel.

[image]

Once you have selected that source, you will need to merge the two queries together using whichever join method is appropriate.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem like these functions are available in 2010. This will be a daily task, so I was hoping that I could use a formula. Even if I could match the existing references in order to pull in the New reference, I could use conditional formatting to pick out where manual intervention is required.

Comment: I found a computer still using Excel 2010 and it can be done on that version as well. You will need to select "From other sources" and then  "From Microsoft query" and then choose your excel file.

Comment: If automation is your goal, I would definitely consider using R (I like the RStudio IDE). You can can easily join these tables using packages like dplyr (a package is like an add-on component that someone has developed for the R language). There are tons of tutorials on the software, RStudio, and a lot of help here at SO as well.